# table migration with sql without using programming language like JSP, PHP

Tags: mysql, data-migration

I have three table,

```
tblstock              --> StockID(Primary Key),ProductCode,Status,
tblstockhistory       --> StockID(tblstock table StockID, 1:N),Qty,invoceNo,MRP
tblstockinoutrtnstats --> StatsID,ProductCode,StockIN
```

i want to do the migration,That is need insert the Stockin countin  tblstockinoutrtnstats ,

my details are,

that is Productcode pull from tblstock table,product quantity present in tblstockhistory table,

Is it possible to do the migration with sql alone without using programming langugage like PHP,JSP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.

Query:
Your going to want to use an ALTER TABLE query. Depending on what flavor of SQL you're using (SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) the statement might look slightly different, but the basic command will be similar to `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name data_type;` (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

Without a Language:
All flavors of SQL I know of allow you to run SQL queries on the command line. Again, it will be slightly different depending on the flavor you're using.
If you're using postgres, type `psql <db_name> <username>`
If you're using MySQL, type `mysql -U <username> <db_name>`
If you're using another version of SQL, look at their help and/or man page to see what the exact syntax you need is for that specific flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. With MySQL and most other databases you can write your SQL, store it in a text file and have it run as a batch by the database. In MySQL it's very simple and the link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html shows your how to do it.